# How do I repoint Developer Powershell to 2022 devenv.exe

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

To reproduce a developer powershell bug, follow the steps below:

- Uninstall Visual Studio 2019
- Install Visual Studio 2022
- Open Visual Studio 2022
- Right-Click a project
- Click "Open in Terminal" in a menu

Developer PowerShell opens and displays the error message:

```
vs : The term 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At C:\Users\jdoe\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:340 char:2
+     vs "C:\EDW\My Project\My Project.sl ...
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...\IDE\devenv.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.4.4
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably (and hopefully) a better solution, but here's a pragmatic one:

- Create directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7` and define a symlink named `IDE` in it that targets the analogous directory in Visual Studio 2022.

Note that *elevation* is required:

```
$oldDir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE'
# Adapt as needed
$newDir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE'


# Create the parent dir. of the missing old dir.
$oldParentDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Split-Path -Parent $oldDir) -ErrorAction Stop

# Create symlink for the last component that points to the desired dir.
New-Item -Type SymbolicLink $oldDir -Target $newDir -ErrorAction Stop
```